# nodejs crashing on losing connection to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When i try to restart mongodb service from services.msc, nodejs server is crashing with this error:
[image]
OR
[image]

My code looks like this

```
_client = await MongoClient.connect(this._config.connectionString, {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
          reconnectTries: 60,
          reconnectInterval: 1000,
          keepAlive: true,
          autoReconnect: true,
        });
```

What ever i do, im not able to catch this exception there fore my node server is crashing. Is there a way to catch this reliably?
To answer a question, why i'm trying this scenario: Sometimes our deployed server is losing connection(to mongoDB) in the cloud and ending up crashing and kick starting new pod in aks.

I'm using mongodb driver, not mongoose.

Comment: Do you have any tailable cursors, change stream or any other persistent data feeds? The connection factory looks fine and screenshots don't provide enough insight. Could you create a minimal reproducible example? A github project or a docker image, whatever you are comfortable with. It seems you are trying to catch the error in the wrong place but without seeing your code it's hard to advise how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `autoReconnect : false` as one of the options in configuration. Documentation [link](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/reference/connecting/connection-settings/)

Comment: Thanks, but that didnt help.

Comment: Can you try `close` event ? You will be able to catch the error in `db.on('close', function(){ })`;

Comment: I've added all 6 events(enum DbEvents {
  PARSEERROR = 'parseError',
  ERROR = 'error',
  TIMEOUT = 'timeout',
  RECONNECT = 'reconnect',
  CLOSE = 'close',
  CLEANUP = 'clean',
  PROCESSEXIT = 'process-exit',
}), but i dont get call back. 
I get callback in case of reconnect and others but not in this case.

Comment: Can you try giving `autoReconnect : true`. By default it is true according to the docs, but I had read somewhere that it is by default true only while using mongoose. 

Ohh I just saw that in my answer, i have mentioned `autoConnect`, actually it is `autoReconnect`. Can you try this? Give `autoReconnect : true`.

Comment: HI Nisarg, Ive tried playing with most of the options given in the docs.